# Stop all processes in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a python program that I develop in PyCharm (PyCharm 2018.3.4 (Community Edition)) on windows 10.

My main process starts a new process using `multiprocessing.Process`. However when I use the 'stop' button in pycharm, python keeps running in the background (I guess the muliprocessing.Process is never killed), consuming my CPU and memory. I there a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried hitting ctrl+c instead of the stop button? That should allow the pool to clean itself up...

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what is the problem with the following ?

```
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process)
proc.start()
proc.join(timeout=5)
proc.terminate()
```

Another solution
use the

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value
manager = Manager()
x = manager.Value('i', 0)
```

for sharing values between process,

once a process change the value 0 to 1, activate

```
proc.join(timeout=5)
proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Not much, however my application starts a tk GUI loop in after the `proc.start()'. Because of this the proc.join is never reached when I press the stop button.